# Use javascript to add a letter in css?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm having issues with my noggin... Please help me answer this question:

is it possible to add a single letter to a string in css? (i would assume that it is by storing the original string and adding a letter at a specific position)

Here is my code:

```
.u_usa{
background-image: url(../images/icons/usa_24.png);
}
```

What I am looking to do is onclick change the css property to:

```
.u_usa{
    background-image: url(../images/icons/usa_24t.png);
    }
```

then when clicked, change it back (removing the "t")...

the issue is that i have SEVERAL different classes that I want to use the same function on, each having a different location for the background image. The thing that stays the same is that one image has a t and one doesnt...

i need one function that, no matter what class im changing, is able to simply change one letter in the css property (whatever class is calling the function)

thank you in advance, If you couldnt tell by my jibberish posting, I have been working on these issues for a while and have fixed just about everything but this one item.

Thank you again...

edit:
what i am trying to achieve is creating a function that when run does a css switch, but is dynamic as to whatever class is running it. i have 60+ different divs that have backgrounds, when clicked i want to add or remove a "t" from the 4th to last character position of the css background image url.

Comment: what are you _really_ trying to achieve?  Dynamically re-writing your CSS files is rarely the right answer...

Comment: @Alnitak - the problem is that i have several (around 60) different div's and twice that images that i want to do this with. I already have created multiple styles for most of the divs but the css is getting out of control. im looking for a more lean way to approach this issue. I am also looking into other options, i just know that the stackoverflow community answers questions faster than it takes to look up alternate methods of doing the same.

Comment: is there only one div of each class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add a second CSS rule for each class with a dual-class selector, e.g.:

```
.u_usa {
    background-image: url(../images/icons/usa_24.png);
}

.u_usa.clicked {
    background-image: url(../images/icons/usa_24t.png);
}
```

and then in your `onclick` event handler, add or remove the `clicked` class from the appropriate elements.

Comment: I ended up changing the rest of my code to work in this manner (i only implemented 10 or so for testing), I didn't want to have a huge CSS file, but it is unavoidable for the tasks that I want to accomplish. In the end product I feel that ill be refactoring everything in javascript anyhow. I appreciate your timely response and wish you well in your endeavors.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of approaches:

#### Toggle Classes

Have one background image specified by one class and a different background image by another class. Find all the elements with one class, loop over them, remove one class and add the other. It's reasonably quick for say less than 100 elements with the same class but might be slow where there are more.

#### Select elements based on background image and change it

Very slow and compute intensive, ok for a small number of elements but that's it.

#### Change the style rule

Find the style rule in the appropriate style sheet and change the value of the background-image property. It's more code (if you have to write the function from scratch, but I'm sure you can find a suitable function and add it to your code collection). It's very fast, regardless of how many elements you need to modify. The only drawback is that it will change *every* element with the class, you can't except some based on logic like you can with the toggle method.

Your choice.

Comment: The problem is that i have 60+ classes, each using a different set of background images.

Comment: The the last option seems best. There are hints on how to get started on [quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/changess.html). If you need more help, post again.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you can make the style inline instead of a class.

Then use the code snippets below

from normal to 't' image

```
var img = document.getElementsByClassName('className')[0].style.backgroundImage;
img = img.replace('.png','t.png');
document.getElementsByClassName('className')[0].style.backgroundImage = img;
```

and reverse

```
var img = document.getElementsByClassName('className')[0].style.backgroundImage;
img = img.replace('t.png','.png');
document.getElementsByClassName('className')[0].style.backgroundImage = img;
```

Or

Make two different classes and change the class everytime you need to change the background-image

```
document.getElementsByClassName('className')[0].setAttribute('class','newClassName');
```

Comment: this code won't work - you can't access properties of a DOM collection like that.

Comment: I am sorry...my bad. thought of inline styling instead...will shortly come up with a new solution. It can be done using jQuery though.

Answer (score 0):

we can use addClass function in JQuery to do that when click on a button.course we can not do that without javascript

Answer (score -2):

That's not possible with CSS I'm afraid. You'll have to use javascript, or more likely a library such as jQuery to create that functionality.